# Difference in column properties in R

Tags: r, rstudio

## Why are these columns formatted differently?

```
#create vectors
row.name <- c(letters[1:15])
column.A <- c(rep(c(0.75, 0.75), 7), 0.75)
column.B <- c(rep(c(0.75, 0.75), 7), 3.0)

#make into data.frame
tbl <- data.frame(row.name, column.A, column.B)
```

In the linked output tbl, each of the values for column.A are to the left side of the cell (like a character) and in column.B, all values are on the right. The only difference is that the last value was changed from 0.75 to 3.00.

```
#Class is "numeric" & identical for both columns
class(tbl$column.A[1:15])
class(tbl$column.B[1:15])
identical(class(tbl$column.A[1:15]),class(tbl$column.B[1:15]))

identical(tbl$column.A[1:14],tbl$column.B[1:14])

#of course the last cell is different (0.75 vs. 3.00)
identical(tbl$column.A[15], tbl$column.B[15])
```

Output table:

[image]

If column.A & column.B are identical, why are they depicted as different in the output table? Obviously, something is different about them, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You using the Rstudio viewer I assume? This is not a problem with base R?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm using R-Studio. Do you know why this would appear differently? There must be something different that causes them to behave differently.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Rstudio. If you run `View(tbl[,c(3,1,2)])` they look the same. For some reason the column order matters.

Comment: That's odd. when I run View(tbl[,c(3,1,2)]) I get the same issue. R-Studio Version 1.0.136, running R version 3.2.3. I guess it's time to upgrade both.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on "inspect element" in the viewer.

Because all items in column A are identical, the viewer displays it as type unknown:

```
<th title="column 2: unknown" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="rsGridData" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 52px;" aria-label="column.A: activate to sort column ascending"><div>column.A</div></th>
```

But, because items vary in column B, it's treated by the viewer as type numeric:

```
<th title="column 3: numeric with range 0.75 - 3" class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="rsGridData" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 51px;" aria-label="column.B: activate to sort column ascending"><div>column.B</div></th>
```

If you changed the last item in column A to literally any value other than 0.75, it would be treated as numeric like column B and right-aligned like you would expect.